# How to get the name of the module, controller and action in Laminas framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, laminas

I’m usign the latest Laminas framework and I want to know how to get the name of the module, controller and action? I need those names in a view helper.
Thanks in advance!

I did it in Zend Framework 1 but now Laminas has changed a lot.